# How to have tab completion in for json in vscode

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

data.json

```
{
   "property1": "value 1",
   "property2": "value 2"
}
```

In Javascript

```
let a = await fetch('./data.json');
```

I fetch the file into javascript like above ☝.
Is that possible `a.` to show `property1` and `property2` in auto-complete?

Comment: `a` is not the object above. It’s a [`Response`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Response) object that you need to call [`json`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Response/json) on and `await` its return value, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript for this:

```
interface Data { property1: string; property2: string; }

let a = await fetch('./data.json').then(res => res.json() as Promise<Data>);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvZAHKAez2jAE8BGALmQGcwpQBzAbnyJKnICYb7GQrZAF8AUKIA2EMMiwBeWQHc4wGTGkIAFgAoA5ADoA9ABMMcfQCtahELoCU+sJoghtUCLWRyAfMne1La1c7WU8ABSIAW2BaCAAedExvOxZRIA)

Comment: are there any extensions available to achieve this?

Comment: @Arunachalam VS Code supports TypeScript out of the box. You don't need additional extensions. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript